# How to capture the tags applied by git decorate

Tags: git, shell, stdout

What goes on here? Why are the two outputs different?

```
$ git log --oneline -n1
7dbee6d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) some commit msg

$ git log --oneline -n1 | head
7dbee6d some commit msg
```

The piping to 'head' was the simplest example I could find to illustrate the problem. The problem prevents me from e.g.:

- Piping to a file including the git decoration
- Piping to "grep", e.g. to grep for certain tags

system:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- git version 2.17.1
- GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Both commands give the same output at my end.

Comment: Which operating system, shell and git version?

Comment: @user3729611 What is the `| head` part meant to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `log` manpage:

> ```
> --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
>
>     Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If short is
>     specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and
>     refs/remotes/ will not be printed. If full is specified, the full 
>     ref name (including prefix) will be printed. If auto is specified,
>     then if the output is going to a terminal, the ref names are shown
>     as if short were given, otherwise no ref names are shown. 
>     The default option is short.
> ```

So when called with `--decorate=auto`, the behavior will change depending whether stdout is a terminal or not. If you pipe `git log` output somewhere, `stdout` will not be a terminal.

The default is `short`, but you may have `auto` somewhere in your git options.

To get the same behavior in both cases, call it with `--decorate=short`